# No resource identifier found for attribute fontFamily in package android

Tags: android

I face error

```
No resource identifier found for attribute fontFamily in package android
```

in my android application , what is the problem ?

Comment: Where exactly do you use that attribute? Layout XML file? Please post the context of that usage and write which SDK are you targetting since not all attributes are available for all SDK versions.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are referring to a `TextView`, `android:fontFamily` was added in API Level 16 and will not be available on older devices. You have your Android build target (e.g., Properties > Android in Eclipse) to something older than API Level 16.

Comment: have you gotten the fontFamily attribute to work in any configuration, for any build?

Answer (score 8):

You will need to compile with API 16 or above.

From the command line use `--target 19` or higher, as in:

```
android update project --path . --name MyApp --target 19
```

BTW: To see how the target numbers match the API numbers, use `android list targets`

I hope somebody finds this useful, as I spent hours trying to solve the following error:

> Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:fontFamily'